# Encountering errors when trying to deploy create-react-app project to GitHub Pages

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, frontend, github-pages

I've followed the official documentation but to no avail.

I've added "homepage" to package.json, also added the "deploy" and "pre-deploy" scripts, installed "gh-pages".

This is what I get when I run "npm run deploy":-

```
> my-app@0.1.0 predeploy
> npm run build


> my-app@0.1.0 build
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Compiled successfully.

File sizes after gzip:

  46.24 kB  build\static\js\main.16e5ee86.js
  1.78 kB   build\static\js\787.28cb0dcd.chunk.js
  541 B     build\static\css\main.073c9b0a.css

The project was built assuming it is hosted at /my-app/.
You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.

The build folder is ready to be deployed.

Find out more about deployment here:

  https://cra.link/deployment


> my-app@0.1.0 deploy
> gh-pages -d build

node:events:368
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn git ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:282:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:477:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:288:12)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:477:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn git',
  path: 'git',
  spawnargs: [ 'config', 'user.name' ]
}
```

This does not really make any sense to me and I'm not sure what I should do next. I've tried updating my npm and all but the problem persists.

And yes, I have run "npm run build" before all this. Also, yesterday I tried to create another react app using "create-react-app" but for some reason it did not work as well even after trying multiple times in different folders. And today it worked (for some reason) and I created a react app but the issue with deployment remains.

Comment: The error is saying that the spawned `git` command failed. Do you have `git` installed and configured?

Comment: Yes, I have .  Actually I had pushed my project onto github as it is a requirement for hosting at Pages. But, the 'gh-pages' branch did not get created as it should have.

Comment: You could always [do it manually](https://gist.github.com/chrisjacob/833223)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll try doing it manually.